# Добавить дополнительный запрос в функцию

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Есть вот такая функция, которая добавляет заказ в таблицу:

```
    function insert_order(){
    
        global $wpdb;

        // Добавление данных заказа

        if(is_admin()): $order_status = 4;
        else:  $order_status = $this->order_status;
        endif;
     
        $terms = get_the_terms(key($this->cart->places), 'event-type'); 
     
        $args = apply_filters('evpl_pre_insert_order', array(
            'user_data'         => $this->user_data,
            'order_price'       => $this->cart->price,
            'place_amount'      => $this->cart->amount,
            'order_details'     => serialize($this->details),
            'order_date'        => current_time('mysql'),
            'order_status'      => $order_status,
            'order_hash'        => md5(current_time('mysql')),
            'order_room'        => $terms[0]->name
        ));

        $result = $wpdb->insert(
            WP_PREFIX.'evpl_orders',
            $args
        );

        if(!$result)
        return false;
    
        return $wpdb->insert_id;
    
    }
```

Пытаюсь добавить в неё дополнительный запрос, который будет отправлять другие данные заказа в другую таблицу:
Мой итог:

```
    function insert_order(){
    
        global $wpdb;

        // Добавление данных заказа

        if(is_admin()): $order_status = 4;
        else:  $order_status = $this->order_status;
        endif;
     
        $terms = get_the_terms(key($this->cart->places), 'event-type'); 
     
        $args = apply_filters('evpl_pre_insert_order', array(
            'user_data'         => $this->user_data,
            'order_price'       => $this->cart->price,
            'place_amount'      => $this->cart->amount,
            'order_details'     => serialize($this->details),
            'order_date'        => current_time('mysql'),
            'order_status'      => $order_status,
            'order_hash'        => md5(current_time('mysql')),
            'order_room'        => $terms[0]->name
        ));

        ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

        
        $result = $wpdb->insert(
            WP_PREFIX.'evpl_orders',
            $args
        );

        if(!$result)
        return false;
    
        return $wpdb->insert_id;
    
        $order_stats = array(
                'order_id' => $this->order_id, 
                'event_id' => $event_id, 
                'order_room' => $terms[0]->name, 
                'order_status' => 1
        );

        $results = $wpdb->insert( 
            WP_PREFIX.'evpl_stats_order',
            $order_stats
        );

        if(!$results)
        return false;

    }
```

Первый запрос срабатывает, а мой второй нет, ошибок тоже никаких нет. Во вторую таблицу ничего не заносится.

Comment: У вас же `return $wpdb->insert_id;` посреди кода. Всё, что ниже, не выполняется. Чего же вы хотите?

Comment: Если опустить в конец как Вы говорите, то страница просто обновляется и вообще ничего не заносится в таблицу.

Comment: Кажется я что то не так делаю с ```if(!$result)
        return false;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таком случае проверяйте ошибку с помощью `print_r(1);exit;`.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Спасибо, нашёл ошибку.